# Is there a more efficient way of getting a list of rows from a database and then instantiating them into models?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm coding in CodeIgniter and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do what I'm doing.

1. (Controller) Get all rows from database, selecting only the `ID`
2. (Controller) Loop through those `ID`'s, adding a new Model (with the `ID`) to an array
3. (Controller) Passing the array of models to the views.

I'm just worried that I'm querying the database twice. Once for getting the `ID`, then another for creating the object, which will then query the database again.

Is there a way to do this in less steps?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can create a single SQL query that will return all the info you need, I don't see any reason why your model shouldn't return a complete datastructure with all the info required.